# Update an android app

Tags: android, app-store, updates

I have to create a custom app store for android apps. The app store application will download the applications from the server and install it in the users device. Suppose the application gets updated on the server, and server sends the push notification to the device for the update.

Now how can the app store application un-install the previous application and install the new one?

What code examples can help to implement it ?

**EDIT :**

[njzk2](https://stackoverflow.com/users/671543/njzk2) Thanks a lot !!!

So will just use the Installing app logic even for update :

For installing : [Android: install .apk programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967669/android-install-apk-programmatically)

Comment: why would you uninstall the previous version ? you would loose the user's data !

Comment: Ok. So w/o un-install, what should the app-store do to update other apps ?

Comment: the same as for a plain install. there is nothing special to do.

Comment: Will there be no package issues, and an alert message from android that the application with the same package already exists? And if the install works in both the cases, then how should the app-store install the application ?

Comment: if the application is signed with the same signature, it will work. Just like it works when you update an application from play or when you update using adb or eclipse.